# A surjective endomorphism (of a Noetherian ring) is injective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

The problem is stated as follows:

"Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $\theta$ be a ring homomorphism from $R$ to $R$. Show that if $\theta$ is surjective then it is also injective."

Regardless of the right solution, I don't understand why is the following wrong:

> We have $\theta: R\to R$. By the isomorphism theorem $R/\ker\theta\cong\operatorname{Im}\theta$. Since $\operatorname{Im}\theta = R$, it follows $\ker\theta =0$, so it's injective.

Harsh criticism will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have the right solution for that somewhere, but I wanted to first remove this wrong approach from my head.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $S$ be a non-zero ring and take infinity many direct <del>sum</del> product $R = S^{\mathbb{N}}$. Then the homomorphism defined by
$$ f \colon R \to R,\ (r_1, r_2, r_3, \dotsc) \mapsto (r_2, r_3, r_4, \dotsc) $$
is clearly surjective but its kernel is $\ker f = S \times 0 \times 0 \times \dotsb \neq 0$.

So naive inference "$f \colon R \to R,\ \operatorname{im}f = R \implies \ker f = 0$" is wrong.

Comment: Great example, thanks. So the isomorphism theorem here looks like $R/S \cong R$ ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. $  $

Comment: TS asked about **Noetherian** rings.

Comment: @Corvus No. She asked why the same is not true (or more precisely, why the above argument is wrong) without Noetherian assumption.